# Angular 2 - data binding not working

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

In my TS I have:

```
private accountTypes = [
    { accountTypeId: 1,
      displayName: "Individual - Taxable",
      isTaxable: 1,
      subcategory: "Taxable" },
    { },
    { }
    ... more objs
]
```

and I have this in my HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let question of section?.questions">
    <select class="q-select"
            [(ngModel)]="acttypetest"  // BIND HERE
            name="answerForQuestion{{ question?.questionId }}">
        <optgroup label="{{subCat?.subCat}}"
            *ngFor="let subCat of accountTypes; let i = index;">
            <option *ngFor="let acctType of accountTypes"
                [ngValue]="acctType">
                    {{ acctType?.displayName }}
            </option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

When I try to bind the first element in my `accountTypes` array to `acttypetest` like this it works properly:

```
setSelectedAcctType() { 
    this.acttypetest = this.accountTypes[0];
}
```

But when I try to bind it like this (with a regular object that **exactly** matches the first element in my `accountTypes` array, it doesnt work:

```
setSelectedAcctType() { 
    this.acttypetest = {
        accountTypeId: 1,
        displayName: "Individual - Taxable",
        isTaxable: 1,
        subcategory: "Taxable"
    };
}
```

Why doesnt the second way work if it is the same exact formatted object as the first element in my `accountTypes` array?

Comment: Because 2 apples with exact look are still count as 2 different apples.

Comment: Even if they match in terms of schema or even values they are not referring to the same object in memory.